# Change the keyboard layout in LightDM

Tags: keyboard-layout, lightdm

I installed LightDM on an Arch Linux system (using pacman) and it runs fine, except, that if I try to type a special character (like "@", "$", ...) in the user or password field it doesn't do anything. I'm using the gtk3 greeter, but it doesn't work with other greeters aswell.

I configured the keyboard and the locale like described in the Arch Linux installation guide and it also says in the top right corner of LightDM "de_DE.utf-8".

Comment: Which special characters don't work? Are they the ones that require `AltGr`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I think LightDM uses for some reasons an American keyboard layout (for example "-" on my keyboard becomes "/"). But if I login without LightDM and start Cinnamon everything works fine.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was that I forgot the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-keyboard.conf . I created it with the content:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
    Option "XkbLayout" "de"
    Option "XkbVariant" "nodeadkeys"
EndSection
```

and now LightDM works.

Comment: Here is the pertaining [Arch documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Using_X_configuration_files).

Comment: The `localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts` command will list all available keyboard layouts/maps.

Comment: Nowadays, the Arch documentation recommends `localectl [--no-convert] set-x11-keymap layout [model [variant [options]]]` over manual edits – it works well in 2022.

Answer (score 3):

I edited `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and under the section `[Seat:*]` I added a line:

`display-setup-script=setxkbmap de`

to get my layout (I use `dvorak` but I think you'll want `de` perhaps) layout in the display manager/greeter. The installed keymaps can be listed with `ls /usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386` and you probably want `de` for yours.

Comment: Thanks, lightdm was using the wrong layout for me ever since I enabled auto login with it. This fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

## On Xubuntu

On Xubuntu, I had to create a file in a different directory:

```
$ cd /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
$ sudo touch 00-keyboard.conf
$ sudo nano 00-keyboard.conf
```

with this contents for a Belgian `be` keyboard:

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=/usr/bin/setxkbmap be oss
```

The command `setxkbmap` is provided by the package `x11-utils`, hence

```
$ sudo apt install x11-utils
```

The available keyboard codes are listed with:

```
$ localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts
```

While you are at it, you might also want to [**ensure that NumLock is active during LightDM login**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435316/39845). This can be achieved by appending an additional line to that very same `00-keyboard.conf` configuration file:

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=/usr/bin/setxkbmap be oss
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Of course, this requires that the `numlockx` package is installed:

```
$ sudo apt install numlockx
```

Answer (score 0):

With my linux mint (which is an Ubuntu derivative, so I suppose it should wok with other Ubuntu based distros):

Looking in file `/etc/default/keyboard`, there is a line like `XKBLAYOUT="us"`.

I replaced `us` by `fr` (for my french keyboard) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

`display-setup-script=setxkbmap de` works for the local console. However it breaks dynamic vnc sessions startup.

If you need to also supports such sessions, ignore command errors, like

```
display-setup-script=/usr/bin/bash -c "setxkbmap de >/dev/null 2>&1 || :"
```