# Change lightdm keyboard layout US to Portuguese Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, locale, lightdm

I'm installing [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/), but I have a problem with the installation of my display manager, [lightdm](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM).

When I [install](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide) and enable lightdm, I think the keyboard layout changes from Portuguese to US.

Changing the keymapping with:

```
# localectl set-locale LANG=pt_PT.UTF-8
```

only works until lightdm launches, then the keymapping reverts to US. The same occurs when I try to change it permanently by changing to `KEYMAP=br-latin1` with:

```
# sudo nano /etc/vconsole.conf
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130858/change-the-keyboard-layout-in-lightdm

Comment: TY, _StrongBad_. The solution from there was modified for Portuguese, and incorporated in the answer below, which also touches on another issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found the answer to my question, I believe that it can be applied to other languages than Portuguese.

The LightDM keyboard layout to Portuguese is done with this command:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap pt
```

I did this as `root`, and I *think* it is the right way, but you can do it has a normal user too, I believe.

I've found this on [Fedora forum](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/77762/lightdm-greeter-has-wrong-keyboard-layout/).

For `set-x11-keymap` to work, first, we need to install package `libxkbcommon`, without that will give you an error message.

I've found it on [ArchLinux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=242135).

**UPDATE**

I asked this question also in Arch Linux forum and this [answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1840182#p1840182), solves the problem too, adding to the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-keyboard.conf, these configs:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XkbLayout" "pt"
    Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection
```

and reboot...